# Property does not exist on type 'Vue' lint error

Tags: typescript, vue-component

I'm trying to call a getter from within a computed function. It needs to be computed as I'm doing a sort and I get an infinite loop with a regular function

```
@Component({
  props: {
    "skill-id": String
  },
  computed: {
    sortedSkillAdmins():PersonSkill[] | null {
      var peopleSkills = this.skill.personSkills
      ...
    }
  }
})

export default class SkillDetailsTab extends Vue {

  get skill(): Skill {
    return this.$store.getters.skillById(this.$props.skillId);
  }
}
```

I'm getting a lint error `TS2339: Property 'skill' does not exist on type 'Vue'.` on the `this.skill` in sortedSkillAdmins() and can't figure out how to make it happy. Am I calling it incorreclty? It seams to work fine in the browser, but I'm worried its poor code and will trip me up later.